# opencv Contour Removal

Tags: c++, opencv

I am having an issue with contours in opencv, mainly with how they are handled. for reference look at this tutorial:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html#moments

The Part that is giving me pause is when I try to interact with the contour opbject they declare in that I cannot figure out how to remove items from the collection without breaking everything. the object declarations from the tutorial are included for those who did not click it below.

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
```

Now, I may have missed this somewhere in the opencv documentation, but how do I remove a contour from the list of returned contours safely?

By safely I mean that I tried a simple

```
contours.erase(contours.begin()+15);
```

which cause run time issues with the hierarch item that gets returned with it, but when I included

```
hierarchy.erase(hierarchy.begin()+15);
```

I lost more than a single contour, so I am kind of at a loss as to how I remove a single contour from the collection that gets returned to me.

Edit:

Based on the response I got how can I get OpenCV to return me a series of contours that I can easily remove unnecessary contours from?
Cheers

Comment: You are using contours with hierarchy and you expect the contours are disjoint? Usually contours are all related to each other. That's why if you delete one, then some others get removed.  You have to find another way to manage enumerable blobs. In my case, it often involves extensive use of drawContours.

Comment: @Thomas I would like to see an example of your method, just so I can get something working I will worry about the best way to do it later.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the hierarchy the best way to remove contours is to set some value in the hierarchy to some flagged value.

So you walk all the contours by walking the hierarchy, if the contour needs to be 'deleted' then set the index in hierarchy to 0 (or -1) or something.

Remember hierarchy also has children contours if you select this.